# 403 Forbidden on Console.log When Calling <img src="{{item.photo}}"> on Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, http-status-code-403

I made an APi call and want to retrieve {{item.photo}} which contains value of something like

```
http://example.com/img/1461212599.jpg
```

there is no problem when i opened it in a browser. the image is shown fine. but got error 403 forbidden when accessing it from Ionic 3 app.

What could be the problem and how to resolve it?

**UPDATE**

**Rest Provider**

```
getItembyCategory() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
     .toPromise()
     .then(data => {
        return data;
     })
     .catch(err => {
        return err;
     })
   }
```

**Home.ts**

```
import { RestapiProvider } from './../../providers/restapi/restapi';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  items; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: RestapiProvider) {

  }

  getProduct(){
    this.restProvider.getItembyCategory()
     .then(data => {
       this.items = data['details']['item'];
    });
  }

  generatePriceArray(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
 }

ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.getProduct();
}

}
```

**Home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list inset >
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
          <ion-thumbnail item-start>
            <img src="{{item.photo}}">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <h2 text-wrap>{{item.item_name}}</h2>
          <p *ngFor="let price of generatePriceArray(item)"> {{price.price}}</p>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post the actual URL here - it sounds like the image is not 100% public. Does it work in incognito mode? If it requires auth, browser may be sending the right cookies over, but your API call may not be.

Comment: Could you show your `code`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. i update with the code. pls let me know if u need more

Comment: it is not require auth

Comment: Could you show your `HTML` and `ts` code too?

Comment: added with HTML and ts

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue.
Its caused by Hotlinking Protection by Cloudflare. On default, hotlinking protection is enabled. Simply switch it off on Scrape Shield Page to disable it.

Hopefully may help other who have the same issue like me.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you use `property binding` instead of `string interpolation` like so.

```
 <img [src]="item?.photo">
```

Comment: What is the value of `item.photo`?

Comment: It seems `user is authenticated but not authorized to access the resource (or image)`.

Comment: i tried to replace the domain name with the server ip and it works

Comment: OK. Great. What will you do next?

Comment: but i can not use server ip for it. its imposible

Comment: i actually use cloudflare. but already whitelist the images folder. i don't know why still does not work

Comment: Your issue is not a coding issue. Hope you'll get the network admin's support or helpdesk support of host provider.

Answer (score 0):

When getting 403 at response it means that the server refused your request.You need check if your IP has been blocked by this server.You said you can open it at browser,which means that your IP not blocked by server.You need check if you need add headers at your request when you visit this url. If no headers with your request,the server may think it is an robot visit the block your request and return 403 to you.